# "The fourth next to it" - does this express an item four items away?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Which one do you want? This?
>
> No, the **fourth** next to it.

Should we use **four** or **fourth** here? When they say the one next to it, they apparently have not used the word **first**.
I want to say that I do not want the one next to it. I want the thing that its distance is four items away.

Comment: The fourth what? The fourth *one*. *one* was in your question, so why not use it?

Comment: Without knowing the context, I can say that "fourth" might refer to a portion of some greater whole. Alice: I would like a piece of pizza. Bob (looking at a pizza divided in four): Which one do you want? This? Alice: No, the fourth next to it.

Comment: Admittedly, this sort of construction would be seen more frequently with "third" and "half."

Answer (score 2):

While it may be understood you might want to say:

> No, I want the fourth one to the left/right of it

However I would say,

> No, I want the fourth from the left/right

Where you count the number of items the object you want is from the edge of the row. Although usually it is occasionally easier to point and just say "No, that one is he one I want."